# Debug error highlighting cpp file using QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: qt5

Делаю расцветку cpp файла используя класс унаследованный от QSyntaxHighlighter
переопределяя метод highlightBlock(const QString& str) правда использую рекурсию в нем.
Почему может выскакивать следующая ошибка при запуске

```
Debug error
Program: C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
Module: 5.8.0
File: global\Qglobal.cpp
Line: 3070

ASSERT: "uint(i) < uint(size())" in file
```

Причем нажимая "пропустить" появляется снова и так 3 раза после чего приложение запускается и работает нормально как ожидается
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на проверку в массиве, i > size() массива вот оно и ругается.
В исходниках Qt я нашёл такое в 3-х контейнерах: 1. QBitArray; 2. QByteArray; 3. QString. Возможно есть ещё...

Comment: Странно до этого работал с ними и ничего подобного не было, но если

Comment: дело в QString то где эта проверка происходит???

Comment: #include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include"my_class.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
  //  MainWindow w;
   // w.show();
    QTextEdit txt;
    QFont fnt("Lucida Console",9,QFont::Normal);
   txt.document()->setDefaultFont(fnt);
    new Hilight(txt.document());
    QPalette pal=txt.palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Base,Qt::darkBlue);

Comment: pal.setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::yellow);
    txt.setPalette(pal);
    txt.resize(640,480);
    QFile file("D:\\Qt_Projects\\After_break\\QProgressBar_QSpinBox\\QProgressBar_QLCDNumber\\class.cpp");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    txt.setPlainText(QString(file.readAll()));
    txt.show();
    return a.exec();
}
Это main.cpp Что не так не могу разобраться.

Comment: Highlight - мой класс унаследован от QSyntaxHighlighter с переопределенным методом highlightBlock(const QString& str)

Comment: попробуйте `file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);` заменить на `if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return; `

Comment: Методом комментариев определил что ругается на 
new Hilight(txt.document()); Но почему - вопрос !!!!!!!!
В книге так написано.